# Wordpress: hook XML-RPC to prevent duplicate posts

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

I have a wordpress photo blog that reposts images from instagram for me.
The posts are created from an IFTTT applet through XML-RPC.
For some reason duplicate posts are often created (this is a bug thats been around for years and ifttt dont seem to care about it).

To get around this, I create each post with a title containing the unique instagram ID of the photo. I would like to use this to compare the new post_title to existing ones.

I have tried hooking into **transition_post_status**, this works for normal posting but all posts coming though XML-RPC are still published. They seem to bypass that action.

Can I hook into XML-RPC when it creates the post and prevent it if it has an already existing post_title?

Here is the code that works for normal posts:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'check_for_duplicates', 10, 3);

function check_for_duplicates($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $post->post_type === 'post') {

      global $post;
      global $wpdb ;
      $title = $post->post_title;
      $post_id = $post->ID ;
      $wtitlequery = "SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_title = '{$title}' AND ID != {$post_id} " ;

      $wresults = $wpdb->get_results( $wtitlequery) ;

      if ( $wresults ) {
          $error_message = 'This title is already used. Please choose another';
          add_settings_error('post_has_links', '', $error_message, 'error');
          settings_errors( 'post_has_links' );
          $post->post_status = 'draft';
          wp_update_post($post);
          wp_die( $error_message );

          return;
      }
      //return $messages;
    }
  }
```

Comment: do_action( 'xmlrpc_call', string $name ) this hook will help you as it will fires after the XML-RPC user has been authenticated but before the rest of the method logic begins.

Comment: Ive looked into this hook. Can I use post data along with it?